# Macros with extra parameter at the end?

Tags: c, macros

I am not exactly sure what to title this.  But, this is the third time I have seen this phenomena in a C macro.

```
#define sigemptyset(what)   (*(what) = 0, 0)
                                         ^
                                         eh?  why not just ((*what) = 0)
```

Is there a point to that extra zero?  To my understanding (1, 0, 0, 0), for example, would just evaluate to 1 (the first entry).

Comment: It's the other way around. The comma operator evaluates to the _last_ argument. In this case zero, indicating success regardless of the input.

Comment: @doynax Not quite: the comma operator *evaluates* all operands (sub-expressions), but the result is the result of the last sub-expression.

Comment: I hate the comma operator, and this fooled me yet again, so it's an excuse for an upvote.  I'm trying to find one upvote per day to balance the many downvotes:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma operator yields the value of its right operand, not the left operand.

**UPDATE:** as pointed out by [@Kninnug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249237/kninnug)  in the comments, `sigemptyset` is a POSIX function specified to return an `int` (specifications: [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigemptyset.html)). By using `(*(what) = 0, 0)` it guarantees that the macro yields an `int` even if `*(what)` is of another type than `int` (the `sigemptyset` argument should be of type `sigset_t`).

<s>Two things come to my mind with your macro definition:
If it had `(void *) 0` as the right `,` operand, it could mimic a function that returns a null pointer:</s>

```
#define sigemptyset(what)   (*(what) = 0, (void *) 0)

int *p = sigemptyset(q);
```

It can be useful if all your other `sig` functions are supposed to return pointers.

The second thing that comes to my mind is to allow debugging by changing the `0` with a `printf` call when needed:

```
 #define sigemptyset(what)   (*(what) = 0, printf("sigemptyset\n"))
```

Comment: OP is (probably) referring to an implementation of the POSIX-defined [`sigemptyset`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigemptyset.html) operation, which must return a(n `int`) 0. Hence the second expression.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to focus on the POSIX function.  You addressed the part I was confused about. That it guarantees the return function is of the correct type (when return type does not necessarily matter).